# Redshift - Converting UTC data to other timezones

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert data from UTC to various European timezones. I am using a case statement and find only the first condition in the case statement is executed while the other conditions are not checked.

```
SELECT sale_id,appointment_time,timezone,
   case when timezone = 'EDT' then (appointment_time + interval '-4' HOUR * 1)
        when timezone = 'BST' then (appointment_time + interval '1' HOUR * 1)
        when timezone = 'CEST' then (appointment_time + interval '2' HOUR * 1)
        when timezone = 'EEST' then (appointment_time + interval '3' HOUR * 1)
        when timezone = 'MSK' then (appointment_time + interval '3' HOUR * 1)
        when timezone = 'WEST' then (appointment_time + interval '1' HOUR * 1) 
        else null
        end as NewTime
   FROM sales
```

Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Don't handle timezone conversions on your own, use [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed else just add before end and use `dateadd` function

```
SELECT sale_id,appointment_time,timezone,
   case when timezone = 'EDT' then dateadd(h,-4,appointment_time)
        when timezone = 'BST' then dateadd(h,1,appointment_time)
        --------------
         --------------
       else null
        end as NewTime
   FROM sales
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, forgot to add it as part of my message. It still does not convert properly with the else condition..

Comment: @KevinNash you have to use dateadd function

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use built in convert_timezone function. It would be faster since you don't need to use a case

```
SELECT sale_id, appointment_time, timezone, 
  convert_timezone(timezone, appointment_time) as NewTime
FROM sales
```